# TabActivity and onNewIntent for NFC

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am working on an application that implements a `TabActivity` with two different Activities.

The application uses NFC and in order to manage the `tag_discover` I have the two methods `onNewIntent` and `onResume`.

When I open the interface and I use the first Activity everything works well, I am able to read a tag and do some action `onNewIntent` when the tag is read.

When I switch to the second tab and I come back in the first Activity the application doesn't work correctly. It seems that `onNewIntent` is not called.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the [foreground dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html#foreground-dispatch). Please read the docs and also take a look to the API Demos example and the NFC one under your sdk/samples